# Laggy window when displaying images for the first time with JScrollPane

Tags: java, image, performance, swing, jscrollpane

I am trying to display a bunch of ImagePanels in a JScrollPane. The problem with this application is that every time a new row of panels enters the viewport the whole window freezes for a small amount of time. Once scrolled through to the end though, the window will not lag again.

What is the cause of this lagging and how can I prevent it from happening in the first place?

My guess is the panels don't get painted until they are scrolled to. So I tried to call repaint on them after adding them to the background but that didn't work :(

MainClass.java:

```
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class MainClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                MainFrame frame = new MainFrame();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

MainFrame.java:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class MainFrame extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -254980289568295701L;

    public MainFrame() {

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);

        JPanel background = new JPanel();
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(background,
                 JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED,
                 JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
        ImagePanel ipanel;

        background.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(this.getWidth(),
                                              this.getHeight() + 3000));    

        scrollPane.setOpaque(false);
        scrollPane.getViewport().setOpaque(false);
        scrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar().setUnitIncrement(20);
        add(scrollPane);

        for (int i = 0; i < 40; i++) {
            ipanel = new ImagePanel();
            ipanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 400));
            ipanel.setSize(new Dimension(300, 400));

            background.add(ipanel);
        }

        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

ImagePanel.java:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

public class ImagePanel extends JPanel {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1997246878999790104L;
    private Image image;
    private int width;
    private int height;

    public ImagePanel() {
    width = 300;
    height = 400;
    BufferedImage bufferedImage = new BufferedImage(2000, 2000, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    Graphics2D g2d = bufferedImage.createGraphics();
    g2d.setColor(Color.white);
    g2d.fillRect(0, 0, 2000, 2000);
    g2d.setColor(Color.black);
    g2d.fillOval(0, 0, 2000, 2000);
    g2d.setColor(Color.yellow);
    g2d.fillOval(1500, 300, 400, 400);
    g2d.fillOval(1200, 600, 400, 400);
    g2d.fillOval(900, 900, 400, 400);
    g2d.fillOval(600, 1200, 400, 400);
    g2d.fillOval(300, 1500, 400, 400);
    g2d.dispose();
    image = bufferedImage.getScaledInstance(width, height, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this);
    }
}
```

Comment: *"In order for this to run you have to replace the placeholder in the constructor with a file path string to a directory that contains only images."* Or, you could make it easy on us and create a bunch of images in code..

Comment: Likely the culprit is `image = image.getScaledInstance(width, height, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH)` ..

Comment: @AndrewThompson I tried putting that line in the constructor of the class with fixed width and height. Although it should be called once before any scrolling action now, the problem persists.

Comment: For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). Generate the images in code, like I suggested in the first comment.

Answer (score 0):

I changed your code to us a `JLabel` to display the image.

It takes longer to load, but the scrolling worked fine:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

//public class ImagePanel extends JPanel {
public class ImagePanel extends JLabel {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1997246878999790104L;
    private Image image;
    private int width;
    private int height;

    public ImagePanel() {
    width = 300;
    height = 400;
    BufferedImage bufferedImage = new BufferedImage(2000, 2000, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    Graphics2D g2d = bufferedImage.createGraphics();
    g2d.setColor(Color.white);
    g2d.fillRect(0, 0, 2000, 2000);
    g2d.setColor(Color.black);
    g2d.fillOval(0, 0, 2000, 2000);
    g2d.setColor(Color.yellow);
    g2d.fillOval(1500, 300, 400, 400);
    g2d.fillOval(1200, 600, 400, 400);
    g2d.fillOval(900, 900, 400, 400);
    g2d.fillOval(600, 1200, 400, 400);
    g2d.fillOval(300, 1500, 400, 400);
    g2d.dispose();
    image = bufferedImage.getScaledInstance(width, height, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
    setIcon( new ImageIcon(image) );
    }

//    @Override
    protected void xxxpaintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
//        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this);
        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
    }
}
```